# Unity Lighning (shader, lightmap or blender UV issue?)

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I have the following scene

[image]

As you can see the ball in front of me has a very extreme shadow on it's back. How could I make it less extreme? I would like to still see the triangles that compose the Ico sphere but darker and without having to change the sun's position.

I tried to play with my light values, shader value, changed shaders, etc. but without any success. I guess I'm lacking some basic knowledges regarding lightning. Any help / tip would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: What sort of shader is on the ball, now? It looks almost like a toon shader from this screenshot, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: @rutter It's a Standard shader with Metallic and Smoothness to 0 and a little bit of Emission

Comment: From the image that poly looks totally black, could you confirm if it is brighter with other light sources on it? Just want to make sure it is not a flipped normal.

Comment: Thanks @Mr.Bigglesworth, I had flipped normals on my ball (not that one, the one from the image eh). Now it's fixed!

Comment: Brilliant! I'll put it as an actual answer then for anyone else with the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Models which have light issues or seem to have a permanent black poly may have flipped normals and will not display light correctly. Whichever 3d modelling program is used to make the models will be able to flip a normal for you.